# Android Media player errors and HLS

Tags: android, streaming, android-mediaplayer

I need a set of errors that the native Android Media Player may throw when a try of playing HLS stream ends up in the onError() method... in other words, what kind of error will be thrown if media player cannot deal with hls on a particular device... here is a list of all known errors to make things easier. I'd be even thankful for eliminating errors that for sure won't be thrown if it's about the stream format

```
MEDIA_ERROR_BASE        = -1000,

ERROR_ALREADY_CONNECTED = MEDIA_ERROR_BASE,      // -1000
ERROR_NOT_CONNECTED     = MEDIA_ERROR_BASE - 1,  // -1001
ERROR_UNKNOWN_HOST      = MEDIA_ERROR_BASE - 2,  // -1002
ERROR_CANNOT_CONNECT    = MEDIA_ERROR_BASE - 3,  // -1003
ERROR_IO                = MEDIA_ERROR_BASE - 4,  // -1004
ERROR_CONNECTION_LOST   = MEDIA_ERROR_BASE - 5,  // -1005
ERROR_MALFORMED         = MEDIA_ERROR_BASE - 7,  // -1007
ERROR_OUT_OF_RANGE      = MEDIA_ERROR_BASE - 8,  // -1008
ERROR_BUFFER_TOO_SMALL  = MEDIA_ERROR_BASE - 9,  // -1009
ERROR_UNSUPPORTED       = MEDIA_ERROR_BASE - 10, // -1010
ERROR_END_OF_STREAM     = MEDIA_ERROR_BASE - 11, // -1011

// Not technically an error.
INFO_FORMAT_CHANGED    = MEDIA_ERROR_BASE - 12,  // -1012
INFO_DISCONTINUITY     = MEDIA_ERROR_BASE - 13,  // -1013

ERROR_NO_LICENSE       = MEDIA_ERROR_BASE - 14,  // -1014
```

Comment: I can only see https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/av/+/android-4.4.1_r1/include/media/stagefright/MediaErrors.h